# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 8 supplied

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

```
def read_csv():
    f = open("DriverInfo.csv", "at")
    f.truncate()
    f.close()
    database = []
    filename =  "DriverInfo.csv"
    f = open(filename,"rt")
    contents = f.read()
    rows = contents.split("\n")
    for each in rows:
        columns = each.split(",")
        if len(columns) < 2:
            return database
        else:
            database.append(columns)
            con = lite.connect(db)
            with con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute(" INSERT INTO Speeders VALUES(?,?,?,?(columns))
                con.commit()
```

What this is trying to do is use 2 CSV files and link them through SQL, in order to match 2 pieces of information later on in the program, but I have tried for ages and it keeps giving me the same error message that there are 4 columns used but 8 supplied, but when I change it to 8 question marks, it tells me this: table Speeders has 4 columns but 8 values were supplied. I really don't get it and I would be grateful for any help

As an extra note; Speeders uses 4 columns in the CSV file, and DriverInfo uses 3

Comment: It should look like this: (" INSERT INTO Speeders VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(columns))

Comment: Can you verify there are only 4 items in your `columns`? Like by printing length or contents of it.

Comment: def create_database():
        global db
        con = lite.connect(db)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Speeders")
        cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE "Speeders" (
        "NumberPlate" TEXT NOT NULL,
        "UKNP" TEXT NOT NULL,
        "Distancenumber" INTERGER NOT NULL,
        "MPH" REAL NOT NULL
        );''')
        con.commit()

Comment: I am asking you to `print len(columns)` or `print columns`. With that you can see if there are 4 items in `columns` variable.

Comment: It says that there are 8

Comment: So there is your problem. It should has only 4 items in it and _you_ should change your code where you get `columns`

Comment: Ah, thank you. It works now

Comment: You are welcome. :) Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make this question does not list under unanswered questions I felt like I should make an answer out of comments.

Please check the content of your `columns` by printing its length (`print len(columns)`) it must have 4 items in it. If it's not containing four items, you should correct your code that creates `columns`.